# MySQL IF THE ELSE

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm new to MySQL after many years working with T-SQL (MSSQL) and I'm having trouble with a simple if exists update else insert issue...

The table is wp_usermeta in WordPress. I'm trying to create a procedure to update a user's meta value for a certain key.

Here's what I have so far that is not working:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_INSUPD_MetaValue( IN KeyName char(50), IN UserID INT, IN MetaValue longtext)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = KeyName and user_id = UserID ) THEN
    UPDATE wp_usermeta
    SET meta_value = MetaValue
    WHERE meta_key = KeyName and user_id = UserID
ELSE
    INSERT INTO wp_usermeta
        (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    VALUES
        (UserID, KeyName, MetaValue);
END IF
END
```

So far, I'm getting an error at "ELSE" and "END IF". Doesn't matter if I put a semicolon after the statement.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA,
Owen

Comment: You need to terminate the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries with `;`. Depending on what you are using to CREATE/ALTER your SP, you may need to [change the delimiter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Comment: You also might want to learn about [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in MySQL, because that might allow you to skip the `IF EXISTS... THEN... ELSE`.

Comment: If you do use `IF ... END IF`, you also need a semicolon after `END IF`. The whole construct counts as a statement, and all statements need a semicolon terminator.

Comment: Finally, I suggest you consider avoiding stored procedures in MySQL. You may be accustomed to writing stored procedures given your T-SQL background, but MySQL's implementation is inferior. Poor performance, no debugger, no packages, no compiler, no standard library, no atomic deployment, etc. I think you will continue to be disappointed if you use stored procedures in MySQL.

Comment: If this will be called from WordPress code, I respectfully suggest you use [update_user_meta( $user_id, $keyName, $value );](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/). It does what you want, it exploits the object cache if present, and it's fully debugged.

Comment: This will not be called from Wordpress code.

Comment: I have attempted to terminate the update and insert queries with ";", but that also does not work. I'll have to try changing the delimiter (strange that I have to do that for something so simple and basic)...

Comment: Bill Karwin: I had to resort to a stored procedure because IF/THEN/ELSE is not supported outside of a stored procedure or function. AND I cannot use the ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax because I'm not inserting the key (the key is an auto-increment index): I'm finding the row based on the two values, not the key... Unless I'm missing something (could be since I'm used to T-SQL)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A syntax error occurs at the ELSE statement because the code appears to lack a semicolon after the UPDATE statement. A semicolon may be added after the sentence "WHERE meta_key = KeyName and user_id = UserID;".

Additionally, double check to make sure the procedure's delimiter is set to something other than a semicolon (for instance, $$) before creating it and then resets it to a semicolon once it has been formed.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_INSUPD_MetaValue( IN KeyName char(50), IN UserID INT, IN MetaValue longtext)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = KeyName and user_id = UserID ) THEN
    UPDATE wp_usermeta
    SET meta_value = MetaValue
    WHERE meta_key = KeyName and user_id = UserID;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO wp_usermeta
        (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    VALUES
        (UserID, KeyName, MetaValue);
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```